# Status of Irish critical skills permit if work from USA office on L1 visa

Tags: visa, resident-permit, ireland, foreign-employment, l1-visa

I am an Indian citizen and hence hold an **Indian Passport**. I am currently working in Ireland with **critical skills employment permit** which is valid for 2 years after which I do not need a permit to work in Ireland and can take up permanent residency.

The company that I currently work for has its parent office in US. It has been around 8 months on Critical Skills visa for me in Ireland.

**Questions** -

---

If an L1 visa is raised so that I can work with the parent company in US:

> - Is my critical skills permit at risk?
> - Can I now not get Ireland stamp 4?
> - Is it possible to work on L1 visa in US and still hold my irish visa permits/rights?
> - After working for some time in US on L1 visa, if I want to switch to another company in ireland, Will I have to apply for work visa
>     again?
> - Does L1 visa changes my employer?

`Any insight to above will be helpful. I did research online but critical skills information on sites only talk about eligibility criteria and do not mention scenario which I am facing`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it's possible:

> In accordance with section 24(1) of the Employment Permits Act 2006 as
>   amended should a non-EEA national, for whatever reason, cease to be
>   employed by the employer during the period of the Critical Skills or
>   Green Card Employment Permit’s validity, the permit and the employer’s
>   certified copy must be returned to the Department of Jobs, Enterprise
>   and Innovation within four weeks from the date of termination or
>   cessation. A permit holder or an employer who fails to comply with
>   this subsection is guilty of an offence. All such permits which are
>   returned to the Employment Permits Section in line with this will be
>   changed to a Cancelled status on the Employment Permits Management
>   System and these permits will no longer be valid.

It *might* be possible is you are still employed by the same Irish company, not officially employed by the US office but I don't know if that is allowed on an L-1 visa. You do have to have worked for the non-USA office for at least 1 year. Ask your company's (perhaps the parent company) immigration lawyers.

Comment: Hi, any help here please? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/requirements-for-b-and-l1-visa Thanks